# I found the error while opening the Android Studio for the first time on HP Omen?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

When I click on the icon of the Android Studio, this box comes and it never opens. The progress bar reaches till here no further.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling the latest version?

Comment: Please add Andriod studio version number in question and java version(hoping java Jdk is already installed)

Comment: my android studio version is 2.3.3

Comment: I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved as when I have seen my system language, it is in Hindi and then I change it to English and the problem solved!